# Data Selection & Visualization Tool

Tags: feature-selection, data, visualization

I am looking for a tool that will show neatly all the rows from a large table (100GB+) for complex selection conditions from an sql/text/csv table.

DB may be on linux or windows.

Looking for easy learning curve, simple tool with GUI to scroll over many many rows manually.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at dc.js (which uses Crossfilter and D3.js)

[Dc.JS](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/)

Examples of dc.js visualization are available [Here](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/)

Crossfilter supports showing million or more rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a look at [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/).
Splunk also allows you to easily visualize this data, add pivots, and even apply Machine Learning models using their MLTK.